# What are Sending Words™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

I thought I'd try my hand at creating one of these Word™ puzzles.

--

If words have a certain property, I call them Sending Words™.

```
Sending Word™    Non-Sending Word™

ACT              PORTRAY
TEA              COFFEE
CRUX             PROBLEM
KNOW             REALIZE
USED             RECYCLED
YUCCA            PERENNIAL
BEGIN            START
PLIED            WORKED
TOFFEE           CARAMEL
WRONGED          BETRAYED
```

I hope the above is readable enough. Here is a CSV:

```
Sending Word™,Non-Sending Word™
ACT,PORTRAY
TEA,COFFEE
CRUX,PROBLEM
KNOW,REALIZE
USED,RECYCLED
YUCCA,PERENNIAL
BEGIN,START
PLIED,WORKED
TOFFEE,CARAMEL
WRONGED,BETRAYED
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A Sending Word™ is a word which…

> The letters contained within flow either ascending or descending within the alphabet between A-Z, in other terms the word cannot use letters above or below the initial flow of the word which is set by the first two letters. A Non-Sending Word™ doesn’t conform to this rule.

Comment: How will TOFFEE and YUCCA fit? The series will be broken when the characters repeat.

Comment: @Techidiot "the word cannot use letters above or below the initial flow of the word" - Repeated letters would still fall into this process.

Comment: Ok! Perfect +1 it is

Comment: That us why it's called ASENDING word :P.